# C++ Apple Mach-O Linker Error/Symbols "::" Not Found for Architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, operator-overloading

I have the following header file (Student.h)

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
int id;
string name;
string school;

public:
/*
 * Default ctor
 */
Student();

/*
 * Overloaded ctor
 */
Student(int id, string name, string school);

/*
 * Compares two students by ID for equality
 */
bool operator == (const Student& other) const;

/*
 * Compares two students by ID for ordering
 */
bool operator < (const Student& other) const;
};

#endif /* STUDENT_H_ */
```

And here is my implementation (in another file called Student.cpp):

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool Student::operator==(const Student& other) const{
return(Student::id == other.id);
}

bool Student::operator<(const Student& other) const{
return(Student::id < other.id);
}
```

And then finally a main.cpp file which references both files:

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Student.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
bool equal;
Student s1(111, "Jeff", "Rockywood High");
Student s2(100, "Bobby", "Carmel High");
equal = (s1==s2);
cout << equal;
}
```

I am getting an error from xcode telling me that:

the Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
Student::Student(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `Student(int id, string name, string school);`?

Comment: Its in the header file...

Comment: That's a declaration, where's the definition?

Comment: So you are saying `class Student {
int id;
string name;
string school; ...} ` doesn't serve as a definition? This is news to me...

Comment: Unless you didn't write this code you already know the difference between a declaration and a definition of a member function, you've provided the definitions of `operator==` and `operator<`, where are the definitions for the constructors?

Comment: I didn't write the header file...I wrote the code in the other two files

Comment: `I wrote the code in the other two files` great! Why haven't you written any code for the constructors? To put it another way how is the program supposed to know how to construct a `Student` when you haven't told it how to do it?

Comment: So this is what was needed, right? `Student::Student(int id,
                 string name,
                 string school){
    
};`

Comment: Almost, but that won't initialize the class members with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

By placing `#include "Student.cpp"` in the Student.cpp file I had included the same file twice, without realizing it. Thus, `Student::Student` was defined twice...and thus the duplicate symbol error.